# Passing column name as input to select statement in procedure

Tags: mysql

```
SET stscolvalue = 'SELECT '+stscol+' FROM idt_resource_'+resid+'_user WHERE GUID=' + 
     guid+' limit 0,1';
```

It dosen't returning correct value of the column. Also i tried the `EXEC(stscolvalue)` but it showing sql syntax error. Help me please.

Comment: Print the `stscolvalue`

Comment: What kind of errors and return values do you get, what are you expecting?

Comment: can you please explain me clearly